# Select Query from 3 tables with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, foreign-key-relationship

I Have 3 Tables with foreign keys to each other.
I want to write a SQL Server Stored Procedure to select records from one of them.

[image: My tables]

Now, let's suppose that i want all the Winner records referring to the Player records referring to The Game with the ID=2, how can i proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: You would apply an INNER JOIN with a filtering where clause; http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have specified **all the Winner records** So that i have used the left join for player and game. But the Overall code works according to the where condition.

Try This,

```
select w.* from Winner w
left Join Player p on p.ID_player = w.player_FK
left join Game g on g.ID_game = p.Game_FK
where  Game.ID_game = 2
```

Comment: @Selva can you please tell me how to perform same above operation with Group By like select all latest winner record for all Games.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `SELECT` and `INNER JOIN` then to filter on GameID 2 you can use a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT ID_Winner, Name, Lastname, Player_FK
FROM Winner
INNER JOIN Player on Player.ID_Pplayer = Winner.Player_FK
INNER JOIN Game ON Game.ID_game = Player.Game_FK
WHERE Game.ID_game = 2
```

Comment: when i do that  in my method which returns a list<WinnerDetails> (the class for winner records that calls the stored procedure) i get : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ID_player

Comment: @SlimaneAgouram - this is a different question.  You should accept an answer here (if it helped you with the original problem) and then post a new question with the details of your problem, as well as a snippet of the code which is causing the Exception.

Comment: Your answer helped me with my problem, only thing left is to check that i have everything in place to make it work.
Thank You.